# How to use local variables in stored procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, variables

if I want to select any id from a table and want to insert it's value in another table as foreign key then how i will do it through stored procedure?

Comment: How are you accessing the database: ADO.NET, Entity Framework, LINQ to SQL...? Are you looking for help in your ASP.NET code, or in the SQL code?

Comment: I removed the ASP.NET tag as this question isn't at all about ASP.NET, but dealing with stored procedures in SQL. It would be useful to know what database engine you're using.

Answer (score 19):

An example of how I would approach this.

```
DECLARE @MyID INT;

SET @MyID = 0;

SELECT @MyID = [TableID]
  FROM [MyTable]
 WHERE [TableID] = 99;

IF @MyID > 0
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO [MySecondTable]
         VALUES (@MyID, othervalues);

END
```

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL style variables:

```
DECLARE my_variable1 int;
DECLARE my_variable2 int;
BEGIN
  my_variable1 := 25;
  SELECT INTO my_variable2 id FROM my_table1;
  INSERT INTO my_table2 (my_field1, my_field2, id) VALUES ('XXX', 'YYY', my_variable2);
END;
```

Comment: SELECT INTO my_variable2 id FROM my_table1;

Doesn't work for me... is it corrent?

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INTO"

Answer (score 0):

Oracle style variables:

```
DECLARE v_MyVariable1 NUMBER;
DECLARE v_MyVariable2 VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN
    v_MyVariable1 := 0;
    SELECT INTO v_MyVariable2 CUSTOMER_NAME
        FROM CUSTOMERS;

    SELECT INTO v_MyVariable1 CUSTOMER_HISTORY_SEQ.NEXTVAL FROM DUAL;

    INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS_HISTORY (CUSTOMER_ID, CUSTOMER_NAME) VALUES (v_MyVariable1, v_MyVariable2);

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            NULL;
END;
```