# Creating Stored Procedure compilation error

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure in oracle but everytime i try to add it to the database i get an error saying `Procedure created with compilation errors`

I cannot execute it (also get an error). I imagine something is wrong with my actual procedure but i cant figure it out. Here is my procedure which i am trying to create:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPBILL @CLIENT_ID VARCHAR2(6)
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT C.CLIENT_NAME, B.ROOM_ID, R.ROOM_COST, T.TREAT_NAME, T.TREAT_COST, (ROOM_COST*(B_END_DATE-B_START_DATE)+TREAT_COST) AS INVOICE
    FROM CLIENTS C, ROOMS R, TREATMENTS T, BOOKING B, PRESCRIPTION P
    WHERE C.CLIENT_ID=B.CLIENT_ID
    AND R.ROOM_ID=B.ROOM_ID
    AND B.CLIENT_ID=P.CLIENT_ID
    AND P.TREAT_ID=T.TREAT_ID
    AND C.CLIENT_ID=@CLIENT_ID
END;
```

Comment: Did you check if your select statements running ok?

Comment: @DevelopmentIsMyPassion yes it does

Answer (score 0):

Try like below

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPBILL (CLIENT_ID VARCHAR2)
AS 
BEGIN
   SELECT C.CLIENT_NAME, B.ROOM_ID, R.ROOM_COST, T.TREAT_NAME, T.TREAT_COST, (ROOM_COST*(B_END_DATE-B_START_DATE)+TREAT_COST) AS INVOICE
   FROM CLIENTS C, ROOMS R, TREATMENTS T, BOOKING B, PRESCRIPTION P
   WHERE C.CLIENT_ID=B.CLIENT_ID
   AND R.ROOM_ID=B.ROOM_ID
   AND B.CLIENT_ID=P.CLIENT_ID
   AND P.TREAT_ID=T.TREAT_ID
   AND C.CLIENT_ID= CLIENT_ID 
END;
```

Comment: what is type of Client_id in database?

Comment: @user3112130 What happens if you remove last And clause which is AND C.CLIENT_ID= CLIENT_ID  and then try to create proc again

Comment: @user3112130 Also try removing CLIENT_ID VARCHAR2(6) and create proc again

Comment: Are you even able to create simple procedure with just one select statement inside it? Are you sure that your query doesnt throw any error?

Comment: @DevelopmentIsMyPassion parameter shouldn't have `(6)`, this is only for variable declarations.

Comment: ok so, my select statement is working 100%, but i made a simple one line procedure which gives same error

Comment: Ok then you have some other issues which you should look more deep into. I suggest you to accept this answer as your way of creating procedure was wrong and i showed you how to do it. If you are still not able to find issue then you should ask new question.

Comment: The select statement does not end with a semicolon

Comment: @tvCa which semicolon ? didnt understand you

Comment: The SELECT statement, which is the block of code, between BEGIN and END;

Comment: @user3112130 Please do as i suggested. You will not get answers. I recommend you to ask new question and accept this as answer as your way of creating procedure was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This must be quite silly but I think its the way you have declared the variable `@CLIENT_ID`

Did you try Declaring your variable like this `DELCARE @CLIENT_ID VARCHAR2(6)`?

Look at this link [How to use local variables in stored procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921074/how-to-use-local-variables-in-stored-procedures)